# Positioning Buttons on top of Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, positioning

I'm looking to create an effect similar to this: https://www.livestrong.org/donation/

I'm just wondering what ways there are to place images/buttons over top of a background.  Would I just do a class/div with a background and then put the buttons within this div?  I'm not sure if it's that simple but I'd like to make sure I'm on the right track before I delve into this.

Comment: Yeah you've got it right. Having a background on the div won't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you're on the right track.You can use`$('#secondDiv').insertBefore('#firstDiv');`,assuming you know JS.I'm sure theres a way through CSS, but it probably won't be the best choice. And you can use `:active` and `:hover` via CSS for the actual buttons if you try to create that. So when the user hovers on it it'll turn into a light grey, then when they click on it, it'll to a yellow color. Here's an example

```
#firstbutton:active{
 background:#009dff
}
#firstbutton:hover{
background:#0148A0
 }
```

Comment: I don't know any JS, so that's not really an option...yet!  I might do the :hover, but it won't need to change colors, as the buttons will be links leading to a PayPal donate page.

Comment: Well its really basic JS. So it shouldn't be much difficulty. Learning JS is important if you want to make websites do things regular CSS and HTML can't do, best thing to do is learn it when you can.

Comment: What exactly would secondDiv and firstDiv do?

Comment: It's pretty staight forward. `secondDiv` would be inserted before `firstDiv`, which means `secondDiv` would be a the bottom. Of course you'd replace them accordingly.